# Can't get scrolling animations to work with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm busy developing a new website.
Now, my problem is to add animations as *fade in* when the user scrolls down.

I've tried various jquery scripts and methods for this.
Even tried a simple script to add a class when scrolled down.
Nothing works with the scrolling method.

Jquery itselfs works.
I've added a simple click on a button for mobile devices, works fine.

Can someone help me, I can't see the problem at the moment.
You can check the website at.

http://www.royaldutchtreeservices.ca/

Thanks!

Comment: you can use [Skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) or [Stellar](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) for this

Comment: Next time consider posting some of the code you tried; it will speed answers.

Comment: Yes it will, only i had no idea what the problem was..
Now ill found that the scroll trigger doesn't work, and have no idea wat it is, maybe the fixed ?

Below i've posted a example of code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend combining the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) with CSS3 animations. The Waypoints plugin will add a class to the element when the user scrolls to it (you can customize the pixel or percentage offset), and your CSS will animate the transition between the states (e.g. opacity and relative positioning).

Here's a simple [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/jmuspratt/pen/AuBxk).

Makes sure to link to the Waypoints plugin. Then your code would look something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="waypoint group">
    <p>Group 1</p>

</div>

<div class="waypoint group">
    <p>Group 2</p>

</div>

<div class="waypoint group">
  <p>Group 3</p>
</div>

<div class="waypoint group">
  <p>Group 4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.group {
  background:#eaeaea;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  padding:50px;
  min-height:600px;
  font:bold 12px/2 arial;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#0196ff;
}

.group:nth-of-type(2) {background-color:#16d44b;}
.group:nth-of-type(3) {background-color:#d45016;}
.group:nth-of-type(4) {background-color:#d41666 ;}

.waypoint {
  opacity:0;
  top:50px;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
}

.waypoint.active {
  opacity:1;
  top:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
},    {

    offset: function() {
        return 400 // trip waypoint when element is this many px from top 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try iscroll.. And add scroll listeners..

You will have to get the position of each element that you want to fade in up front even before initializing iscroll...And initialize iscroll with an onScroll listener.. You'll have to include scroll-probe.js for this.. 
Your onScroll listener can determine at what point of scroll you need to apply the animation.. 
For example

```
If( this.y == myelementsYpostion) {
  $('#myelement').fadeIn()
}
```